# Rails association not fully available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In one of my models (`Article`) I have an association called `translations`:

```ruby
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :translations
  ...
end
```

By some of `article`s not all `translation`s are shown by rendering. I used [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) and could verify that for a specific `article` with two `translations`, I only get one translation. I also tried the following (using pry-debugger inside model class):

```ruby
self == Article.find(id)           #true
self.translations.size             # = 1
Article.find(id).translations.size # = 2
```

Am I missing something here?

**Update:**

using `:force_reload` when accessing the association solves the problem. But how can I avoid using it?

**Edit:**

*Where I fetch translations*

```ruby
def translation_for(locale)
  fallback_locale = (I18n.fallbacks[locale] & locales).first || locales.first
  translations.find { |t| t.locale.to_s == locale.to_s } || translation_for(fallback_locale)
end

def locales
  translations(force_reload: true).map(&:locale)
end
```

The helper function `main_translation` (see below) calls the aforementioned `translation_for` method with default locale (e.g. `:en`)

*Controller*

```ruby
class Profile::ArticlesController < ProfileController
  def index
    @articles = Article
      .published
      .group("articles.id")
      .order(:title)
      .starting_with(params[:letter])
      .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 8)
  end
  ...
end
```

*View*

```haml
%section
  - if @articles.any?
    - @articles.each_slice(2) do |articles|
      .row
        - articles.each do |article|
          .article.col-xs-6
            .well
              :ruby
                translation = article.main_translation # Helper function to get default locale

              = link_to profile_article_path(@profile, article) do
                .article-content
                  .text
                    .title= translation.title
                    %p= raw(shorten(strip_tags(translation.introduction), 50))
                  .clearfix
```

Comment: show the code where you load the article and the code where you set it's translations, it looks like you are having a reference to an article but you are adding it's translation wrong after loading from the database so you need to reload it

Comment: I don't see you looping through the translations, where is that bug appearing? what does main_translation do? does it load the translations? cause you talk about article.translations and you never use it on that code

Comment: it's still not clear where you get the error, you talk about "article.translations.size" and you never use that, can you be more specific? what's the line that shows something wrong and what's the expected value? do you change the translations after loading the articles?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I don't get any errors. That was just an example in console while running pry debugger to clarify what happens.

Comment: with error a meant: what is showing the wrong data and what is the expected data to be shown, something specific, "I have this translations and this line should put this and this but only show this other thing", the problem is that you are not getting all the locales on the "locales" method? do you change translations somewhere else after loading them? also that translations.find looks weird, try with "translations.find_by_locale(locale)"

Comment: The question is: why force loading delivers something different when in the meantime nothing had been changed in the DB? And don't mind the weird line the problem occurs before that line.

Comment: the answer to that question is most likely a bug in your code, that's why I insisted on looking your code helping you debugging it, rails by defaults caches the result of the query so you don't have to use force_reload unless you change something somewhere else (normally you don't even have to user force_reload if you create translations using "article.translations.build ..."), so, rails is doing the wrong query once or you are modifying translations somehow somewhere

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I looked at the stack as well and couldn't see any changes being made to translations. Clearing cache and restarting the server also didn't help.

Comment: can you copy the relevant code from Article and Translation models? you say the problem occurs before that line, can you debug when that happens?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure what else is relevant! I have already posted all the relevant parts. The controller fetches the article and the view values the helper method to get the translation. Virtually nothing else is involved.